# ssh -X - disables menu options

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, x11, menu

My laptop is loaded with Ubuntu 14.04.  I have configured a server with Ubuntu 14.04.  I am able to ssh as well as ssh -X into the server from my machine. On both my machine as well as the server, I have installed a program [downloaded from Github](https://github.com/clavicule/BBTag).

The application in the server opens through a ssh -X connection.  However, after the application opens, the menu options goes missing from the application.  Since the only way to save the image annotations is through the menu File -> Save As option, I could not use the application on my server.

Is there a way to rectify such behavior?

The same thing happens when in putty -> ssh into the server and run the program.

Answer (score 1):

After multiple attempts, I could'nt reproduce your bug (buttons weren't missing). However I had no text at first, so your problem could be related to a missing font on your server, as it was with mine.

You should try to install or change default fonts.

Notice : My server is running an up-to-date archlinux.

Comment: Just to clarify...were you able to see the menu options on your server...do you have to change the fonts on your server..or what is the default font setting on your machine...if you were able to see the menus.

Comment: Yes, I was able to see the menu options. Everything worked fine, but I had to install missing fonts (via the AUR package `all-repository-fonts`. I don't know which font the program used, I didn't have the time to dig in the source code.

Comment: I updated the fonts library in Ubuntu.  I used these `sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-font-meta` which installed around 600 MB of fonts...but still I couldn't get the menu options....I think I will work around with some other solution for the time being.  Thank you very much for all your help and support.